# Tensorflow: my Iris classifier (without estimators) is not working

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm learning tensorflow and, as an exercise, I'm trying to train a classifier for the iris dataset. I tentatively took the network architecture from [the official tensorflow's iris example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/iris.py) and I'm trying to recreate it with the layers API: It should be a neural network with three hidden layers of size 10, 20, and 10; after that, since the iris is a 3-way classification problem, I put a final dense layers of size 3 with softmax activation. This is the code:

```
def parse_csv(line):
    data = tf.decode_csv(line, record_defaults=[[]] * 5)
    return tf.stack(data[:4]), data[4]

trn_data, trn_targ = tf.data.TextLineDataset("../data/train.csv").map(parse_csv).shuffle(200).repeat().batch(32).make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
evl_data, evl_targ = tf.data.TextLineDataset("../data/test.csv").map(parse_csv).shuffle(200).repeat().batch(32).make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 4], name="input")
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None, ], name="target")

# definition of the neural network
a1 = tf.layers.dense(x, 10, activation=tf.nn.relu)
a2 = tf.layers.dense(a1, 20, activation=tf.nn.relu)
a3 = tf.layers.dense(a2, 10, activation=tf.nn.relu)
y = tf.layers.dense(a3, 3, activation=tf.nn.softmax)

# training step
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(tf.one_hot(y_, 3), y)
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_or_create_global_step())

# evaluation of the results
predictions = tf.argmax(y, 1, name="predictions")
correct_prediction = tf.equal(y_, predictions)  # boolean tensor that says if we did good
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
cm = tf.confusion_matrix(y_, predictions)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    for n in range(401):
        if n % 50 == 0:  # see what's going on every 50 steps
            feed_train = {x: sess.run(evl_data), y_: sess.run(evl_targ)}
            acc, c = sess.run([accuracy, cm], feed_dict=feed_train)
            print(c, acc)
        else:  # train
            feed_eval = {x: sess.run(trn_data), y_: sess.run(trn_targ)}
            _ = sess.run(train_op, feed_dict=feed_eval)
```

However, the accuracy is really bad and roughly compatible with the assumption that the network is learning nothing (it hovers around 0.33). To understand better, I printed the confusion matrices at different steps and for different runs: they often show that the network predicts the same outcome for all inputs regardless of their features or labels. A visualization of the parameters of the network with tensorboard shows that the biases change with time but the weights (or kernels, as they're defined in the docs) don't.

There must be an error in the way I pass the data or do the training or whatever, but I can't find it. Could you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use feedable iterators, as explained in https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#creating_an_iterator. The code posted in the question should be corrected as this:

```
def parse_csv(line):
    data = tf.decode_csv(line, record_defaults=[[]] * 5)
    return tf.stack(data[:4]), data[4]    

# notice that there is no `get_next()` at the end
training_iterator = tf.data.TextLineDataset("../data/train.csv").map(parse_csv).shuffle(200).repeat().batch(
    32).make_one_shot_iterator()
validation_iterator = tf.data.TextLineDataset("../data/test.csv").map(parse_csv).shuffle(200).repeat().batch(
    32).make_one_shot_iterator()

handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
x, y_ = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(handle, training_iterator.output_types, training_iterator.output_shapes).get_next()

## [...more code...]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    training_handle = sess.run(training_iterator.string_handle())
    validation_handle = sess.run(validation_iterator.string_handle())

    for n in range(401):
        if n % 50 == 0:  # see what's going on every 50 steps
            acc, c = sess.run([accuracy, cm], feed_dict={handle: validation_handle})
            print(c, acc)
        else:  # train
            _ = sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={handle: training_handle})
```